# how to apply cronjob to automate execution when specific function called while using ajax

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, cron

I want to send page data to external resource through cronjob while using cPanel. But when I did it manually it worked while using cronjob it did not worked.

here is the actual scripts which I want to automate using cronjob
**index.php**

```
<script>
function select_all_booking()
  {
    var check_all = $("#th_booking").is(":checked");
    if(check_all == true)
    {
      $(".check_all").prop("checked",false);   
    }
    else
    {
      $(".check_all").prop("checked",true);  
    }
  }
  function show_ntmp_detail(hb_id)
  {
    $("#show_ntmp").modal("show");
    $.post("?",{hb_id:hb_id,show_error_log:true},function(data){
      if(data!="")
      {
        $(".show_ntmp_history_detail").html(data);
      }
    });
  }

  function get_posted_record()
  {
    var fdatep = $("input[name=fdatep]") .val();
    var tdatep = $("input[name=tdatep]") .val();
    var branchp = $("select[name=branchp] option:selected").val();
    $.post("postdata_stch_posted_record.php",{fdate:fdatep,tdate:tdatep,branch:branchp},function(data){
      $(".show_posted_record").html(data);
    });
  }
</script>
```

actually this code is part of index.php file. Besides the given code, index.php file contains php code within html imbedded.

I want to do some thing like this it send data to external resource after every 10 minutes.

**What I tried**

```
*/10 * * * * /usr/local/bin/php /path/to/index.php
```

Comment: Have you tried _not_ using Javascript and doing it in PHP instead? None of your JS functions gets called?

Comment: Cron can't execute javascript because there's no browser context to do it in

Comment: I try to convert into php code then see what happened